# Фильтрация массива с датами

Tags: javascript

Как отфильтрировать или отсортировать массив дат, чтобы в результате были даты, у которых количество минут равно 15?

Для примера: `08:00, 08:15, 08:30` и т.д.

Массив выглядит так:

```
[1606053689, 1606054260, 1606054979, 1606055307, 1606056084, 1606056434, 1606057644]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const times = [1606076129000, 1606320000, 1606550000, 1606055307, 160605384, 1606036434, 1606057644];

console.log(times.map(e => new Date(e))); // Для визуальности
console.log(times.filter(e => !(new Date(e).getMinutes() % 15)));
```

Comment: подскажите, не на всех массивах работает. Есть даты по типу 14.01 или 15.07, которые делятся с остатком. Может есть ещё способ отсортировать? 

Аналогично пробовал для 30 минут или 60, там к сожалению не всегда срабатывает тоже.

Comment: это часы минуты. Тоесть так получается, что в моём массиве есть даты, которые делятся на 15 с остатком, отсюда я получаю пустой массив. Вообще задача такова, что в массиве должно сокращаться кол-во дат. Тоесть например если есть 8:01, 8:10, 8:15, 8:57, оставить только те что в интервале "каждые 15 минут". Получается что 8:01 не входит в этот интервал, хотя отсчёт должен быть по нему.

Касательно 30/60 минут, я имел в виду, что условие сортировки(выборки) дат может быть и не по 15, а также и по любом другому количеству минут.

Comment: @Alekula, привидите наглядный пример или даже несколько, так будет понятнее. Что есть в начале и что ожидается в конце.

Comment: [1606053689,1606055307,1606056084,1606056434,1606057644]

Comment: @Alekula, все правильно ведь. Вернет пустой массив, т.к. кол-во минут 7 в каждой дате. Или Вам надо было по секундах?